# Counting points between two intersections: Roadway Network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, intersection, network

I have a roadway network as a line feature and crashes as point features.

I need to count the number of points that lie between two intersections of roadways. The biggest problem is the road is also segmented and is not continuous throughout.

Please look at the below image:

Image 1 shows that I have to count points b/w two intersections.
[image]

Image 2 shows roadway segments

[image]

Comment: What license level do you have?

Comment: @EmilBrundage I have advance license

Comment: Do line features always have end vertices at intersections?

Comment: @EmilBrundage Yes, Sir.

Answer (score 3):

Your main goal is to create a single feature between intersections. Here's how to create single feature road features:

Perform an `intersect` on your road segments with output type set to `POINT`.

[image]

[image]

Add XY fields to your intersect points.

[image]

[image]

`Dissolve` points by `POINT_X` and `POINT_Y` fields. Use `OBJECTID` as a stats field, with stats type `COUNT`.

[image]

Select your stats field `COUNT_OBJECTID` < 3 to select non-intersection vertices. Start and editing session and delete these points, or use the `Delete Features` tool.

[image]

`Dissolve` your road segments into a single feature.

[image]

[image]

`Split Lines at Points`. You'll have single segments between intersections.

[image]

[image]

Now you just need to use a `Spatial Join` with your input feature class being your new lines and your join feature class being your crash points. You'll get a `Join_Count` field added which shows how many crashes were joined to each segment.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving a detailed methodology here. Building on this, I have two questions: 
1) can I maintain the link ids of segments that were formed into one link. So if there were 4 segments that were converted to one, would it also have link ids of the four links that were contained into one?

Comment: 2) Each road segment has a traffic volume number. Can I calculate the mean of the volume and then populate the final link(converted into one final line) with the mean number?

Thank you again for uploading a detailed methodology.

Comment: @ParagGupta These sound like different inquiries and should be asked as new questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it.